# How to extend DotNetOpenAuth library for use with OAuth 1.0 to work with special serviceprovider

Tags: .net, authentication, oauth, authorization, dotnetopenauth

I am currently trying to use `DotNetOpenAuth` 1 consumer to integrate with a serviceprovider that requires a few special adaptions. The serviceprovider (VitaDock) requires:

1) message signatures to be computed with HMAC-SHA256
2) That callback parameters must not be present in requests
3) No callback_confirmation will be provided 
4) That the timestamps are milliseconds since january 1st. (instead of seconds)
5) Realm parameter should not be used
6) Nonce to be 36 characters

I have managed to get a simple working solution by implementing these 2 new classes
1) VitaDockConsumer which inherits from MessageHandler which inherrits from DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.Consumer and
2) VitaDockMessageHandler which inherits from  DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.OAuth1HttpMessageHandlerBase

**My questions are:**

1) My solutions "feels dirty" because it breaks with the DRY (Dont repeat yourself - or in this case dont repeat somebody else) principle. In the base classes there are many useful helper methods which handle encoding etc, but since they are defined private, internal or protected, I have not been able to take advantage and I have therefore found my self in need of either implementing the same functionality twice or doing a direct copy. My question is: Is there another route to achieve this. Are there other classes I should extend instead? other patterns?

2) The only way I could figure out to make my solution use timestamps that designate milliseconds rather than seconds was by changing the OAuth1HttpMessageHandlerBase.cs in the library. My question is: Is there another way to do this?

I am new to DotNetOpenAuth, so all help will be greatly appreciated.  I am considering whether a route could be to contribute a new version of OAuth1MessageHanderBase where the timestamp and other helper functions are public or are there good reasons for keeping these helper methods private?

I have not posted my code as it is 700+ lines long, but will of course be happy to do so if needed.

Answer (score 0):

After some investigations.. I have finally found a way to make DotNetOpenAuth work with VitaDock. I chose to extend the Oauth1 MessageHandler and make various changes needed for this provider to be compatible.

In case you came her with a similar question, you might want to check out my solution for changing DNOA

https://github.com/DotNetOpenAuth/DotNetOpenAuth/pull/321

and a small example showing how to use DNOA with VitaDock. It can get receive temperature readings from the VitaDock portal. It could easily be extended to receive other information.

https://github.com/karstenols/VitaDock-DNOA-Sample